# Highlight when add with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

### The goal

Highlight item when I add it to another list using KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I do not how to do, and yes — I have already searched on Google and Stack, but no success; no with "add".

My HTML markup:

```
<div class="tooltip-quantity">
    <p class="float-left">Quantity:</p>
    <form data-bind="submit: Summary.addToSummary">
        <input class="quantity float-left" name="productQuantity" 
               maxlength="2" 
               type="text" 
               data-bind="value: ProductLayout.itemQuantity, 
                                 valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
        <span class="float-left">/@(Model["MeasureName"])(s)</span>
        <button class="btn btn-add btn-mini float-right" 
                data-bind="enable: ProductLayout.itemQuantityValid">
            Add
        </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="@Model["ProductId"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="@Model["ProductName"]" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productMeasure" value="@Model["MeasureName"]" />
    </form>
</div>
```

My **SummaryViewModel**, on JS:

```
function SummaryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray();

    self.addToSummary = function (formElement) {
        var $productId = $(formElement).children("[name=productId]").val();

        var match = $(".summary")
                    .find("li[data-product-id=" + $productId + "]").length;

        if (!match) {
            var $productName = $(formElement)
                                  .children("[name=productName]").val(),
                $productMeasure = $(formElement)
                                  .children("[name=productMeasure]").val(),
                $productQuantity = $(formElement)
                                  .children("[name=productQuantity]").val();

            self.products.push
               (new Product
                   ($productId, $productName, $productMeasure, $productQuantity));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ProductsSummary/Add",
                data: { productId: $productId, productQuantity: $productQuantity }
            });
        }
    }
};
```

*Observation:* `addToSummary` function performs what happens when I add something to a list.

Comment: What do you want to highlight and when? Have you checked this example: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html? It does not highlists on add-remove but does some animation...

Comment: Indeed like in the example on nemesv, I would go for a template binding, using afterAdd to animate the dom that have been created.

Comment: @nemesv Updated. I have already read this link, but no success — isn't exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Skyp Can I animate without template?

Comment: You have to use a template if you want to use the afterAdd ro afterRender

Comment: Could you give us more info about what you want to animate and when, then we could figure out a jsfiddle to help.

Comment: Have you read this?: *Highlight item when I add it to another list using KnockoutJS.* And Skyp, thanks in advance bro!

Comment: Have you considered subscribing to the list you're adding to and animating whatever in the subscribe function?

Comment: @AndrewWalters Actually... Maybe. I've heard about this but did not know that the subscription had this purpose. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example, for which every time your add an item to a list, it is animated : [here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hTwNe/3/)

html:

```
<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
  <div>
    <span data-bind="text: $data"> </span>
    <span>  other stuff not bound </span>
  </div>
</script>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'tmpl',foreach: Data, afterRender: $root.Animate}">
</div>

<span data-bind="text: Data().length"></span>
<button data-bind="click: AddAnItemAndAnimate">AddAnItemAndAnimate</button>
```

Javascript :

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self= this;
  self.Data = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.AddAnItemAndAnimate = function () {
    //just after the push, when the elements will be visible, the function
    //Animate will be call (it is linked to the afterRender of the tempalte)
    self.Data.push('added');
  };

  self.Animate = function(elements, index, data){
    // elements contains the html representing the new item
    $(elements).filter('div').fadeOut().fadeIn();
  };
}
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Comment: Wow! Almost there! This `fadeOut()` before `fadeIn()` is disturbing. I just want to `fadeIn()`. Any ideas?

Comment: self.Animate = function(elements, index, data){
        // elements contains the html representing the new item
        $(elements).filter('div').hide().fadeIn();
    };